# Spin tool curves objects

Tags: mesh

I am trying to use the spin tool to make some basic pipes. When I try to rotate it 90 degrees, this happens:
[image]
The first few faces go away from the pivot point. I tried moving the pivot point, but it does the same thing. For reference, this is the expected behavior:
[image]
I am running Blender 2.8 Beta.

Thanks :)

P.S. First time posting here. If I got any formatting or anything wrong, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to imagine drawing a circle with a centre at the pivot. As your pivot is above the plane, that circle starts in the way you are seeing. Move the pivot parallel to the plane you are extruding and you will get the behaviour you are after.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are a life saver, my friend.